# Windows Registry: What does @="Outlook64Bridge" mean?

Tags: windows, registry

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805802/32-bit-mapi-app-with-64-bit-outlook) question the answer includes modifying the Registry with the following line:

```
@="Outlook64Bridge"
```

Does that mean that I need to add a value for the new subkey, with the Name of `@`, Type of `REG_SZ` and Data of `Outlook64Bridge`?

Does the `@` have any special meaning to the Registry?  I ask this because the second part of the answer also has instructions for adding this to another (already existing?) key.

Answer (score 3):

'@' is the "default" value. In RegEdit, it is the first value listed under the name "(Default)" in any key.